# Using multiple switch statements for a menu program

Tags: c++, menu

So this is a project for school. design a flight reservation program with input validation using menu's. I have gotten the first menu selection to compile and it does work, however adding a second menu generates a c2059: syntax error: 'case'

as well as a c2069: syntax error: '}'

I have been stuck on this since Sunday, with no idea what the error relates to. deleting the '}' in question yields about 12 new error's.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string firstlastname;

int seats = 13;

char selection;
cout << "Please enter your first and last name.\n";
getline(cin, firstlastname);

do
{
    cout << "  Welcome " << firstlastname << " to FlightSpace Airlines!\n";
    cout << "  ====================================\n";
    cout << "  1.  Make a reservation\n";
    cout << "  2.  Check a reservation\n";
    cout << "  3.  Cancel a Reservation\n";
    cout << "  4.  Check flight status\n";
    cout << "  5.  Check Local Weather\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "  6.  Exit\n";
    cout << "  ====================================\n";
    cout << "  Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;

    switch (selection)
    {
    case '1':
    {
        cout << "Make a selection below!";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "There are currently " << seats << " seats available!\n";
        cout << "Would you like to make a reservation?\n";

        char selection;

        do
        {
            cout << " 1: Yes\n";
            cout << " 2: No\n";

            switch (selection)
            {
            case '1':
                cout << "Great! lets get started!\n";
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "You are currenly in Dallas, Texas.\n";
                cout << "Where would you like to go to?\n";

                    do
                        {
                        cout << "1: New York, NY.\n";
                        cout << "2: Shreveport, LA.\n";
                        cout << "3: Seattle, WA.\n";
                        cout << "4: Los Angeles, CA.\n";
                        cout << "5: Miami, FL.\n";
                        cout << "6: Des Moines, IA.\n";
                        cout << "7: Salt Lake City, NV.\n";
                        cout << "8: Charlotte, NC.\n";
                        cout << "9: Minneapolis, MN.\n";
                        cout << "10: Denver, CO.\n";

                        switch (selection)
                        {
                        case '1':
                            cout << "You have selected New York. Is this correct?\n";


                        }


                }


            case '2':
                cout << "Goodbye!\n";
                while (selection != 2);
                return 0;
            default: cout << selection << "is not a valid menu item.\n";

            }
        }



    }







    break;
    case '2':
        cout << "Check a reservation\n";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case '3':
        cout << "Cancel a Reservation";
        cout << "\n";
        break;

    case '4':
        cout << "Flight Status is:\n";
        cout << "\n";
        break;

    case '5':
        cout << "The Local Weather is 79f\n";
        break;

    case '6':
        cout << "Goodbye!\n";
        return 0;
    default: cout << selection << "is not a valid menu item.\n";

        cout << endl;
    }

} while (selection != 6);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of your `do` statements does not have a matching `while`.

Comment: More than one of your `do`s even. Consider using functions.

Comment: This forum is not for debugging your programs. That said, you can try commenting blocks of your code (begin with the innermost `switch`, then comment the containing `do`) until you get no errors, to find were to look for. Better yet, move those blocks of code to different functions so they are easier to read. Alternatively, with most IDEs if you hover on a opening/closing bracket, it will hint you which closing/opening bracket it is paired with...

Comment: Some places need input statements (menu selections).  You prompt the User but don't let them answer.  I recommend using `cin` for gettting the values from the User.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't format the inner do-while loop correctly. The closing bracket for the do-block has no while at the end, and your while statement is inside case 2. You need to make sure that do-while loops are formatted as:

```
do{
    /*code*/
}while(/*boolean statement*/);
```

I would enclose the outermost switch statement in a while(true) loop so that it keeps prompting for the next option until the user quits, then use "break" when the user chooses the quit option, that is: put two "break" statements in the case which ends a loop, one to break the switch-case and one to break the while-loop.

Also, every time you give a prompt to the user, you need to add the cin statement to read what they type, otherwise your program will crash as written.

Comment: comments out the switch statements still results in the same errors, as does adding the missing cin and the while loop.

Comment: Can I see the updated code? I think I was unclear before, I meant that instead of using do-while, use a while loop, as I described above. I recommend counting the parenthesis very carefully and matching which one goes with which.